# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS can't find my printer anymore

Tags: printing

In the beginning when I connected the cables of a "HP Officejet 5610 All-in-One" to my computer (HP Pavilion 6000) with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS everything went just fine. I printed a lot stuff. But after a while I had to go to Windows 10 (same computer, dual boot) because the printer in Ubuntu stopped working. It was because of it that I even installed HPlip 3-16-7 and still Ubuntu does not even let me add a printer. It can't find or recognize any printer at all. Funny! I have another old computer with Zorin Lite 9 (based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and it recognizes that printer. I am puzzled. What did I do or am I doing wrong ?? Was it because of some upgrade or update ?? I am looking forward to hearing from you if you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/574420/cups-service-not-working-cant-find-any-logs

Answer (score 1):

After much trying to fix it I ended up removing HPlip 3-16-7 from my computer and reinstalled the older HPlip 3.15.2-2 and my printer started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar over here: Our "HP Officejet 5610 All-in-One" stopped working after a reinstall of 16.04 - seems I forgot to install the hplip package as an optional one, or hadn't connected the printer during install and automatic printer/scanner recognition.

The hplip distribution version of Ubuntu 16.04 (3.16.3+repack0-1) works flawlessly for us, especially so for the scanner module.