# The system priting service does not seem to be available - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, cups-lpd

The Settings-GUI for printers shows the error message that the system printing service is not available. I have tried reinstalling cups service multiple times. The output for cups status is the following :

```
service cups status 
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: >
 Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-04-23 17:31:35 CEST; 33s ago
TriggeredBy: ● cups.socket
         ● cups.path
   Docs: man:cupsd(8)
   Main PID: 11698 (cupsd)
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 76935)
 Memory: 3.4M
 CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
         └─11698 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
```

which suggests that the service is active and confuses me. I also came across the command `lpstat` for showing various printer related outputs. But I get the following output

```
lpstat -r
scheduler is not running
```

This adds to the confusion. Also read a suggestion about unmasking the service but that gives the following output:

```
service unmask cups.service
unmask: unrecognized service
```

Any suggestions about what exactly is happening and what can I try to get the printing service up again ? Thanks !

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/846177/cups-wont-start

Comment: But the difference is that the user did not have the cups service "active" and instead showed "failed". For me, it appears to be running but still not showing up when I try to add printers or access related settings.

Comment: That's why I stated "Possibly related".  Does http://localhost:631/ not bring up the CUPS page?

Comment: Yes, I was just stating that there is probably a difference in the problems. Thanks !
localhost:631 does bring up the CUPS page.

Comment: So the CUPS did not start then.  I would start with the `cupsd.conf` file as it is what controls the starting of CUPS and if it works.