# Printers disappeared from system-config-printer- 16.04 - xfce4

Tags: printing

[image: I]

Normally I have two printers in this window, one connected by my box-router (network to share) and one for direct usb connexion.
All was working fine until last month, for sure!

Today I have no more printer on my system (!), as you can see in system-config-printer.
If I try "connecter" (connect) , i got:
 `CUPS : « failed to connect to server`
What a disappointment, how can all settings suddenly leave away?
UP:I got no cupsd running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also need to copy **cupsd.conf.default**  file, as others here: [CUPS service not working, can't find any logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574420/cups-service-not-working-cant-find-any-logs?noredirect=1&lq=1). This problem seem to appears often! :/

Check if you're in the same case as us:

```
 locate cupsd.conf.default
```

If it is not in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf, then copy it:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/cups/cupsd.conf.default /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

And restart cups

```
sudo service cups restart
```

Everything should be back. Thanks *ec2011*.