# cups don't print queue anymore

Tags: printing

When I try to print, it only go to queue and wait as "paused" job, so it don't print. 

I have to manually activate all job.

[image]
This issue appears after this one: [CUPS service not working, can't find any logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574420/cups-service-not-working-cant-find-any-logs)

I also have this [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1703947)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by reset task parameters. In printer configuration: Printer>properties>task options> then reset "maintain" ("maintenir jusqu'à" on the screen shot).[image]